# Visual Studio Code - Debugging Promise Callback in Angular

Tags: angular, promise, visual-studio-code, angular-promise

I have the following extension installed in VS Code:
https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code

The debugger works, however I can't set a breakpoint into a Promise callback. For example:

```
  getCatWishesFromBackend() : Promise<string[]> {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/values").toPromise()
                    .then(response => response.json().wishes as string[]);
  }
```

I want to set a breakpoint to that part of the code, what is inside the *then()* part.

How can I do this? If I set a breakpoint in the line of *then()* it only stops the program, when *this.http.get()* is called. When the callback is called, the breakpoint won't be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add an enter and wrap it in curly braces (longer arrow function notation). Make sure to add `return`:

```
return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/values").toPromise()
   .then((response) => { 
      return response.json().wishes as string[]
   });
```